# get list of current windows8 app tiles

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

can I get the list of current available Tiles of my App?

I mean the list of currently not expired tiled showing in my own app. For example if I added 4 tile updates and one of them expired, I need to get the list of remaining three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync() to find all secondary tiles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242208.aspx

Use TileUpdater.GetScheduledTileNotifications() to get all notifications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.getscheduledtilenotifications.aspx

and then TileUpdate.RemoveFromSchedule() to remove one

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.removefromschedule.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to access the notifications/updates that are displaying on a tile.